# Curve25519's Y coordinate of Basepoint origin

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves

The paper [High-speed high-security signatures](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/ed25519-20110705.pdf) by Bernstein et al. introduces the Edwards curve Ed25519.

Concerning the base point $B$, it says that

> $B$ is the unique point $(x,4/5)∈E$ for which $x$ is positive

and $B$ corresponds to the basepoint used on the birationally equivalent curve Curve25519.

So I haven't found on any site information about how do they get that $4/5$ value of the $y$ coordinate in order to get a small basepoint generator.

Is there any reason or origin of that $4/5$? How they determined that $4/5$ was part of the group $2^{255} -19$?

Comment: related  [Base point in Ed25519?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27392/base-point-in-ed25519)

Comment: It's related but it doesn't answer my question. Thanks anyway! It's interesting what it's mentioned there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Over the field $\mathbb Z/(2^{255} - 19)\mathbb Z$, Curve25519 is the Montgomery curve $$v^2 = u^3 + 486662 u^2 + u,$$ and edwards25519 is the twisted Edwards curve $$-x^2 + y^2 = 1 - \frac{121665}{121666} x^2 y^2.$$  The curves correspond by the birational map

\begin{gather}
  x = \sqrt{-486664} \frac{u}{v}, \quad
  y = \frac{u - 1}{u + 1}; \\
  u = \frac{y + 1}{y - 1}, \quad
  v = \sqrt{-486664} \frac{u}{x}.
\end{gather}

The standard base point $P$ for the X25519 Diffie–Hellman function has $u(P) = 9$; the $v$ coordinate is not significant because X25519 works exclusively with $u$ coordinates, so there are two possible points, $P = (9, \pm \sqrt{9^3 + 486662\cdot 9^2 + 9})$.  The choice of $u(P)$ is arbitrary as long as it corresponds to a point of large prime order—it can't affect security—but was made to be the smallest such integer.  The standard base point $Q$ for Ed25519 signature was chosen to correspond to one of the possible choices for $P$, so $$y(Q) = \frac{u(P) - 1}{u(P) + 1} = \frac{9 - 1}{9 + 1} = 4/5;$$ then the $x$ coordinate of $Q$ was chosen arbitrarily from the two options.