# Understanding simplification steps when solving complicated equations in Galois Field

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-arithmetic, finite-field

I just encountered a problem when I tried to understand a basepoint conversion from x25519 to ed25519. I can't really wrap my head around how the value of $x$ can be the stated value below? Can someone please, go through the derivation steps of $x$, especially the modular arithmetic part?

From [Base point in Ed25519?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27392/base-point-in-ed25519?rq=1)

> $$ x^2=\frac{1-(4/5)^2}{-1+(121665/121666)\cdot(4/5)^2} \text. $$ Now
>   by considering the *symmetric* representants (that is, from the set
>   $\{-(q-1)/2,\dots,(q-1)/2\}$) for the elements of $\mathbb F_q$, we
>   can interpret one of the roots of this equation as being positive and
>   the other as negative, corresponding to the signedness of their
>   symmetric representant. The *unique* "positive" solution to the
>   equation above is precisely
>   $15112221349535400772501151409588531511454012693041857206046113283949847762202$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these operations are in a finite field, in particular, a prime field with modulus $p = 2^{255}-19$.

So, for example, $4/5$ is not $0.80$, but $4$ times the inverse of $5$ modulo $p$ (i.e. the number that, when multiplied with $5$, results in the remainder $1$ when divided by $p$). In particular, $1/5$ is $11579208923731619542357098500868790785326998466564056403945758400791312963990$ (because that times 5 is equal to 1 when reduced modulo $p$). The same applies to multiplication, addition and so on - everything is modulo $p$.

The final result is correct, as demonstrated by this Sage code:

```
sage: F = GF(2^255-19)
sage: xx = (F(1)-(F(4)/F(5))^2) / (F(-1) + (F(121665)/F(121666))*(F(4)/F(5))^2)
sage: xx.sqrt(all=True)
[15112221349535400772501151409588531511454012693041857206046113283949847762202,
 42783823269122696939284341094755422415180979639778424813682678720006717057747]
```