# ed25519 base point coordinates

Tags: ed25519

For the ed25519 standard Base Point is $B = (x, 4/5)$. According to [Stack Question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27392/base-point-in-ed25519) the y coordinate equals

```
46316835694926478169428394003475163141307993866256225615783033603165251855960
```

But how this value is received? As I understand $y = 4 \cdot 5^{-1} \mod l$, where $l = 2^{252} + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493$.

So $5^{-1} \mod l$ gives

```
1447401115466452442794637312608598848171423271875981521200390187657090850198
```

and then $4 \cdot 5^{-1} \mod l$ calculates to

```
5789604461865809771178549250434395392685693087503926084801560750628363400792
```

Where do I make the mistake?

Comment: It's 4/5 mod p (the prime), not mod l (the group order).

Comment: What is the value of p?

Comment: 2^255 - 19, according to Google (which probably explains the curve name).

Comment: Yes, that's the origin of the name. Similarly, Poly1305 has nothing to do with the value 1305 :)

Comment: Oh, yes. I am foolish. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please report back with the findings, would be nice if @thedefault. writes a short answer based on it!